# Extracting the scheme from the URL in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the prompt for this question is:
 The ﬁrst part of a URL contains what is known as the scheme or protocol. Frequently-used schemes include http, https, and ftp. A colon always appears immediately to the right of the scheme, and separates it from the rest of the URL. Assume that you are given a Python string variable named url that contains a URL, including the scheme (for example, the string's contents might be something like "http://www.foo.com" or "ftp://www.bar.net", in which cases the respective scheme values would be "http" and "ftp"). Write a sequence of Python string commands that will extract the scheme from the url variable and store it into a new variable named scheme. Your code must work for any URL that is stored in url.

I have no idea how I would even start this, really need help just started Python

Comment: Use [**`urlparse`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html).

Comment: It looks like an assignment. Has your college not prepared you enough to do your homework? I'd complain.

Comment: or something simple like `scheme = var[:var.indexof(':')]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `urlparse`
Eg.

```
from urlparse import urlparse
a = urlparse('http://example.com')
print a.scheme
# http
```

Comment: No problem, would you also mark the answer as accepted so that it will help other programmers in the future :)